# Partizip II von intransitiven Verben

Tags: past-participle, auxiliary-verb

Kann man

> das stattgefundene Ereignis

sagen? Oder müsste es auf jeden Fall

> das stattgefunden habende Ereignis

heißen? Bei transitiven Verben unterscheidet "getötete Person" vs. "getötet habende Person" zwischen Leiche und Mörder, aber wie ist das bei intransitiven Verben? Nur die zweite Variante, weil es ja kein Objekt geben kann? Oder (auch? bevorzugt? ausschließlich?) die erste Variante, weil "habend" überflüssig ist, wenn ohnehin kein Mittel zur Unterscheidung Subjekt vs. Objekt erforderlich ist?

Nach meinem reinen Bauchgefühl könnte es sogar einen Unterschied machen, ob es um Haben-Perfekt- oder Sein-Perfekt-Verben geht (bei "sein" hört sich die erste Variante in meinen Ohren einzig richtig an, bei "haben" bin ich etwas unschlüssig).

Comment: "getötet habende Person"? Erstmal ohne *-e*. Wenn dann aber "tötende Persen" (aber Achtung, "die zu tötende Person" ist wieder "die getötete Person". So oder so. Einfach Mörder. - "das stattgefundene Ereignis" ist richtig und in Ordnung.

Comment: @Em1 Danke für den Hinweis. Die (heute) tötende Person ist jedoch etwas anderes als die (gestern) getötet habende Person. - Ich habe nochmal weiter gesuchmaschint und bei [canoonet](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Finit-Infinit/Part2.html) etwas gefunden; dort wird der adjektivische Gebrauch des PP von intransitiven Verben mit "haben"-Perfekt abgelehnt und bei "sein"-Perfekt akzeptiert (vgl. mein Bauchgefühl).  - Aber die Seite ist halt nicht der Duden ... oder doch vergleichbar sicheres Wissen?

Comment: Habs mir nicht angeschaut bisher und hab keine Meinung zum Thema, außer meinem "Bauchgefühl". Aber canoonet ist schon eine sehr zuverlässige Quelle. Es gilt aber dasgleiche wie beim Duden selbst. Es ist nicht alles heilig, was dort gesagt wird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mit transitiv oder nicht hat das nicht viel zu tun, da im Deutschen auch intransitive Verben passivfähig sind.

Das Partizip 2 wird, wenn vorangestellt, de facto zu einem Adjektiv. Diese werden via *sein* (oder dem "Entstehungsverb" dazu: *werden*)  zugeordnet, wenn die Eigenschaft denn nicht vorangestellt ist.

> Das grüne Auto.
>
> Das Auto ist grün.
>
> Das Bild wurde übermalt.
>
> Das übermalte Bild.

*Stattfinden* bildet sein Perfekt mit *haben* und ist nicht passivfähig.
Um es voranstellen zu können, sollte einer der folgenden Sätze funktionieren.

> Das Ereignis ist stattgefunden... falsch
>
> Das Ereignis wird stattgefunden... falsch

Tut aber keiner. Einzig richtig ist

> Das Ereignis hat stattgefunden.

Daher ist die einzige Möglichkeit

> Das stattgefunden habende Ereignis ...

Das Partizip 1 von *haben* ist in solchen Wendungen aber höchst unidiomatisch. Man kann es allerdings auch nicht einfach weglassen. Ergo...

Die Konstruktion ist in gutem Deutsch nicht möglich. Will man die Zusatzinformation "hat stattgefunden" angeben, so bleibt nur der Klassiker... ein das-Satz

> Das Ereignis, das stattgefunden hat...

Oder einfach ohne... denn *Ereignis* als Subjekt in Kombination mit einem Verb in der Vergangenheit impliziert das Stattfinden.

> Das Ereignis war schön.

Comment: Danke für die Tipps. In meinem konkreten Fall (bzw. das taucht im Original leider zweimal recht kurz hintereinander auf) ist es wohl vertretbar, das eine mit "veranstaltet" statt "stattgefunden" zu beschreiben und das andere mal möglicherweise mit "besagt"

Comment: Also als Lektor würde ich sagen "Ereignisse werden nicht veranstaltet"... höchstens Großereignisse. Es geht, aber es klingt dahingezimmert und nicht rund. Wie ist denn der geaue Kontext? Vielleicht hab' ich eine Idee

Comment: Ja, ok, "Ereignis" war hier auch eine Abstraktion: "Vorbild für die Einladung waren wohl eher die in
der Vergangenheit im Hause regelmäßig stattgefundenen Abendessen [...]" und kurz darauf "Jedenfalls beherrschte das stattgefundene Abendessen tagelang die Schlagzeilen [...]"

Comment: Ich bin hier im hochsprachlichen Gebrauch nicht sicher, aber umgangssprachlich ist `das stattgefundene Ereignis` völlig in Ordnung. Könntest du die (nicht vorhandene) Passivfähigkeit und deren Zusammenhang zur adjektivischen Verwendung noch mal kurz Erläutern?

Comment: Das erste "stattgefundenen" würde ich (wenn inhaltlich zutreffend) durch "veranstalteten" ersetzen. Auch das zweite klingt nicht gut - geht "dieses" statt "das stattgefundene", oder wäre das mißverständlich?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen... also das zweite "stattgefundenen" kann und sollte definitiv gestrichen werden, da es bereits etabliert wurde. Ein "jenes/dieses Abendessen" sollte reichen. Was das erste angeht... da kann man "stattfindenden" sagen, da es ja regelmässig passiert und es eh eine zeitfreie Beschreibung des Hauses ist.. Wie ist das Haus so? Naja, groß, und da finden regelmässig Abendessen statt.

Comment: @Toscho... ok, ich muss es ändern zu "Verben die ihr Perfekt mit haben bilden und die nicht passivierbar sind"... denn dann lässt sich kein Satz bilden "Subjekt - Kopulaverb (sein, werden) - Partizip 2."  Ein Beispiel ist "stattfinden". Ein anderes ist "jammern"... Das gejammerte Lied"... das geht nur, wenn man "Das Lied wird gejammert" auch akzeptiert. Verstehst du was ich meine?